# Can you fuse Tonberry monsters with AOE attacks?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

Is there a way to fuse Tonberry or Don Tonberry with an area of effect attack? For example, Ravage or Blitz?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange @George =)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the infusable abilities for Commandos like Tonberry and Don Tonberry are slim pickings:

- Adrenaline
- Blindside
- Bloodthirsty
- Deathblow
- Faultsiphon
- Lifesiphon
- Powerchain
- Ruin
- Ruinga
- Scourge

Of those abilities, only Ruinga is area-of-effect. You can get it from a number of high-level sources: [Sakura Yule's Monster FAQ](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/619315-final-fantasy-xiii-2/faqs/63731) is a great resource for finding out which monsters get which abilities for the purposes of infusion.